# Trigger a file download with JavaScript and anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I want to tether a file download  using an anchor tag. I tried this :

```
<a href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.js" download>Download</a>
```

But it doesn't work.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, I saw `<a>` tag download have problem with files, which are not native windows formats. Like ".js" in this case. You have 2 solutions, use JavaScript to create download button, or save your file in txt.